# check whether all elements of a list are in equal in R

Tags: r, comparison

I have a list of several vectors. I would like to check whether all vectors in the list are equal. There's `identical` which only works for pairwise comparison. So I wrote the following function which looks ugly to me. Still I did not find a better solution. Here's my RE:

```
test_true <- list(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(1,2,3),d=c(1,2,3))
test_false <- list(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(1,2,3),d=c(1,32,13))

compareList <- function(li){
  stopifnot(length(li) > 1)
  l <- length(li)
  res <- lapply(li[-1],function(X,x) identical(X,x),x=li[[1]])
  res <- all(unlist(res))
  res
}

compareList(test_true)
compareList(test_false)
```

Any suggestions? Are there any native checks for identical for more than just pairwise comparison?

Comment: Not an answer, but you can change your `lapply` to `sapply` and drop a couple of lines from your function.

Comment: The body of your function could be replaced with `all(sapply(li, identical, li[[1]]))`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

How about

```
allSame <- function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1

allSame(test_true)
# [1] TRUE
allSame(test_false)
# [1] FALSE
```

As @JoshuaUlrich pointed out below, `unique` may be slow on lists. Also, `identical` and `unique` may use different criteria. `Reduce` is a function I recently learned about for extending pairwise operations:

```
identicalValue <- function(x,y) if (identical(x,y)) x else FALSE
Reduce(identicalValue,test_true)
# [1] 1 2 3
Reduce(identicalValue,test_false)
# [1] FALSE
```

This inefficiently continues making comparisons after finding one non-match. My crude solution to that would be to write `else break` instead of `else FALSE`, throwing an error.

Comment: +1 for the `Reduce` approach. I had that in mind (all the way down to considering a `while` approach), but my first couple of attempts flopped. :)

Comment: Using `unique` on lists is potentially slow... see `?unique`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Interesting. I've edited that point into the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I woud do:

```
all.identical <- function(l) all(mapply(identical, head(l, 1), tail(l, -1)))

all.identical(test_true)
# [1] TRUE
all.identical(test_false)
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 6):

To summarize the solutions. Data for the tests:

```
x1 <- as.list(as.data.frame(replicate(1000, 1:100)))
x2 <- as.list(as.data.frame(replicate(1000, sample(1:100, 100))))
```

Solutions:

```
comp_list1 <- function(x) length(unique.default(x)) == 1L
comp_list2 <- function(x) all(vapply(x[-1], identical, logical(1L), x = x[[1]]))
comp_list3 <- function(x) all(vapply(x[-1], function(x2) all(x[[1]] == x2), logical(1L)))
comp_list4 <- function(x) sum(duplicated.default(x)) == length(x) - 1L
```

Test on the data:

```
for (i in 1:4) cat(match.fun(paste0("comp_list", i))(x1), " ")
#> TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   
for (i in 1:4) cat(match.fun(paste0("comp_list", i))(x2), " ")
#> FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
```

Benchmarks:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(comp_list1(x1), comp_list2(x1), comp_list3(x1), comp_list4(x1))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>            expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq      max neval cld
#>  comp_list1(x1)  138.327  148.5955  171.9481  162.013  188.9315  269.342   100 a  
#>  comp_list2(x1) 1023.932 1125.2210 1387.6268 1255.985 1403.1885 3458.597   100  b 
#>  comp_list3(x1) 1130.275 1275.9940 1511.7916 1378.789 1550.8240 3254.292   100   c
#>  comp_list4(x1)  138.075  144.8635  169.7833  159.954  185.1515  298.282   100 a  
microbenchmark(comp_list1(x2), comp_list2(x2), comp_list3(x2), comp_list4(x2))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>            expr     min        lq      mean   median        uq      max neval cld
#>  comp_list1(x2) 139.492  140.3540  147.7695  145.380  149.6495  218.800   100  a 
#>  comp_list2(x2) 995.373 1030.4325 1179.2274 1054.711 1136.5050 3763.506   100   b
#>  comp_list3(x2) 977.805 1029.7310 1134.3650 1049.684 1086.0730 2846.592   100   b
#>  comp_list4(x2) 135.516  136.4685  150.7185  139.030  146.7170  345.985   100  a
```

As we see the most efficient solutions based on the `duplicated` and `unique` functions.

Comment: @Frank: Answer updated. Also note: that `microbenchmark` allows to measure even smallest differences.

Comment: A similarly fast answer to `comp_list4` would be `comp_list5 <- function(x) all(duplicated.default(x)[-1])`.

Answer (score 0):

PUtting in my self-promoting suggestion for `cgwtools::approxeq`  which essentially does what `all.equal` does but returns a vector of logical values indicating equality or not.

So: depends whether you want exact equality or floating-point-representational equality.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

The overall best solution:

```
all.identical.list <- function(l) identical(unname(l[-length(l)]), unname(l[-1]))
```

Implementing Frank's solution with a break:

```
all.identical <- function(l) class(try(Reduce(function(x, y) if(identical(x, y)) x else break, l), silent = TRUE)) != "try-error"
```

Continuing with Artem's benchmarking and adding the solution from Jake's comment, speeds are pretty dependent on the objects being compared, but `all.identical.list` is consistently the fastest (or very close to fastest):

```
library(microbenchmark)

all.identical.list <- function(l) identical(unname(l[-length(l)]), unname(l[-1]))
all.identical <- function(l) !is.null(Reduce(function(x, y) if(identical(x, y)) x else NULL, l))
all.identical.break <- function(l) class(try(Reduce(function(x, y) if(identical(x, y)) x else break, l), silent = TRUE)) != "try-error"
comp_list4 <- function(l) sum(duplicated.default(l)) == length(l) - 1L
comp_list5 <- function(l) all(duplicated.default(l)[-1])

x1 <- as.list(as.data.frame(replicate(1000, 1:100)))
x2 <- as.list(as.data.frame(replicate(1000, sample(100))))
microbenchmark(all.identical.list(x1), all.identical(x1), all.identical.break(x1), comp_list4(x1), comp_list5(x1), check = "equal")
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                     expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#>   all.identical.list(x1)   60.3   66.65  125.803   72.90   94.30 3271.5   100
#>        all.identical(x1) 1134.0 1209.45 1484.864 1265.85 1655.95 5085.3   100
#>  all.identical.break(x1) 1156.6 1226.75 1602.869 1337.25 1698.05 5030.4   100
#>           comp_list4(x1)  170.5  179.35  234.169  184.75  200.40 2164.1   100
#>           comp_list5(x1)  173.3  182.35  213.542  187.55  194.50 1704.0   100
microbenchmark(all.identical.list(x2), all.identical(x2), all.identical.break(x2), comp_list4(x2), comp_list5(x2), check = "equal")
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                     expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#>   all.identical.list(x2)   31.0   34.30   47.182   37.65   46.90  180.8   100
#>        all.identical(x2) 1002.8 1059.85 1237.426 1106.65 1278.35 3404.4   100
#>  all.identical.break(x2)  119.4  137.15  156.748  147.60  164.00  340.8   100
#>           comp_list4(x2)  165.0  172.35  189.869  181.20  192.25  334.6   100
#>           comp_list5(x2)  166.6  171.10  188.782  179.25  190.55  394.9   100
x1 <- as.list(as.data.frame(replicate(10, 1:1e5)))
x2 <- as.list(as.data.frame(replicate(10, sample(1e5))))
microbenchmark(all.identical.list(x1), all.identical(x1), all.identical.break(x1), comp_list4(x1), comp_list5(x1), check = "equal")
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                     expr    min      lq     mean median      uq    max neval
#>   all.identical.list(x1)  211.4  217.25  264.978  229.5  258.00  711.4   100
#>        all.identical(x1)  182.2  187.50  218.062  195.3  217.05  499.4   100
#>  all.identical.break(x1)  194.8  207.25  258.043  222.7  266.70 1013.4   100
#>           comp_list4(x1) 1457.3 1495.30 1659.118 1543.0 1806.75 2689.0   100
#>           comp_list5(x1) 1457.7 1502.45 1685.194 1553.5 1769.10 3021.2   100
microbenchmark(all.identical.list(x2), all.identical(x2), all.identical.break(x2), comp_list4(x2), comp_list5(x2), check = "equal")
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                     expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#>   all.identical.list(x2)    3.1    4.45    7.894    6.35    9.85   48.5   100
#>        all.identical(x2)   12.0   15.25   19.404   17.05   22.05   56.1   100
#>  all.identical.break(x2)  114.3  128.80  172.876  144.90  190.45  511.5   100
#>           comp_list4(x2) 1292.2 1342.35 1443.261 1397.00 1472.25 1908.5   100
#>           comp_list5(x2) 1292.4 1364.90 1478.291 1409.50 1484.80 2467.2   100
```

Answer (score -1):

this also works

```
m <- combn(length(test_true),2)

for(i in 1:ncol(m)){
    print(all(test_true[[m[,i][1]]] == test_true[[m[,i][2]]]))
    }
```

Comment: That's pretty inefficient. You only need to do at most `n-1` comparisons, while you are proposing `n*(n+1)/2`.