# How do I test if three variables are equal [R]

Tags: r, equality

I'm trying to do if else statement which includes a condition if three variables in the data frame equal each other.

I was hoping to use the identical function but not sure whether this works for three variables.

I've also used the following but R doesn't seem to like this:

```
geno$VarMatch  <- ifelse((geno[c(1)] != '' & geno[c(2)] != '' & geno[c(3)] != '') 
& (geno[c(5)] == geno[c(4)] == geno[c(6)]), 'Not Important', 'Important')
```

Keeps telling me:

```
Error: unexpected '=='
```

Am I supposed to specify something as data.frame/vector etc...  Coming from an SPSS stand point, I'm slightly confused.

Sorry for the simplistic query.

Comment: The error is that you have to test `==` in pairs (i.e. `a == b & a == c & b == c`). But, of course, you really only need to test 2 pairs as long as, across the two pairs, all three values are included.

Comment: A similar but more general question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813526/check-whether-all-elements-of-a-list-are-in-equal-in-r/18814864#18814864

Answer (score 15):

I see so complicated results, mine is simple:

`all(sapply(list(a,b,c,d), function(x) x == d))`

returns TRUE, if all equals d all equals each other.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a recursive function which generalises to any number of inputs and runs `identical` on them. It returns `FALSE` if any member of the set of inputs is not identical to the others.

```
ident <- function(...){
    args <- c(...) 
    if( length( args ) > 2L ){
       #  recursively call ident()
       out <- c( identical( args[1] , args[2] ) , ident(args[-1]))
    }else{
        out <- identical( args[1] , args[2] )
    }    
    return( all( out ) )
}

ident(1,1,1,1,1)
#[1] TRUE
ident(1,1,1,1,2)
#[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's about numeric values, you can put the numbers in an array, then check the array's max and min, as well:

```
if(max(list) == min(list))
   # all numbers in list are equal
else
   # at least one element has a different value
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
geno$VarMatch  <- ifelse((gene[c(1)] != '' & gene[c(2)] != '' & 
                          gene[c(3)] != '') & 
                          ((gene[c(5)] == gene[c(4)]) & 
                          (gene[c(4)] == gene[c(6)]))), 
                          'Not Important', 'Important')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `==` is a binary operator which returns a single logical value. R doesn't expect further input past your first evaluation, unless you feed it a Boolean `&` for vectors. You may want to modify this, but here's one attempt at a functional programming approach:

```
testEqual <- function(x, y) ifelse(x == y, x, FALSE)

all(!!Reduce(testEqual, list(1:10, 1:10)))  # True
all(!!Reduce(testEqual, rep(T, 3)))         # True

all(!!Reduce(testEqual, list(1, 5, 10)))    # False
all(!!Reduce(testEqual, list(T, T, F)))     # False
```

The double negation is used to convert values to logical vectors, and the `all` command returns a single Boolean. This only works for numeric values or logical vectors.

I'm throwing this out here just for fun. I'm not sure if I would actually use this approach, but any critiques are welcomed.

Comment: This is similar to the accepted answer in the link I posted. Elegant but the problem I have with it is that `all(!!Reduce(testEqual, rep(F, 3)))` will return `FALSE`.

Comment: Ah! Good catch @flodel. Thanks for pointing that out. Still, a fun example to create!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on @John's comment under the OP. This is by far the easiest way to go about this.

```
geno$VarMatch  <- ifelse((geno[c(1)] != '' & geno[c(2)] != '' & geno[c(3)] != '') 
 & (geno[c(5)] == geno[c(4)] & geno[c(5)] == geno[c(6)]), 'Not Important', 'Important')
```

Simpler than the other answers, and can be used with basic subsetting/ assignment too, e.g.

```
geno$VarMatch[geno[c(5)] == geno[c(4)] & geno[c(5)] == geno[c(6)]] <– 'Important'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just come up with simple generic function comparing three elements and then using `mutate` and `rowwise` from `dplyr` apply those to each combination.

```
library("tidyverse")
set.seed(123)
dta_sample <- tibble(
    colA = sample(letters, 10000, TRUE),
    colB = sample(letters, 10000, TRUE),
    colC = sample(letters, 10000, TRUE)
)

compare_strs <- function(one, two, three) {
    if (one == two) {
        if (two == three) {
            return(TRUE)
        } else {
            return(FALSE)
        }
    } else {
        return(FALSE)
    }
}

dta_sample %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(all_cols_identical = compare_strs(colA, colB, colC)) %>%
    # For results
    filter(all_cols_identical)
```

### Preview

```
# A tibble: 25 x 4
# Rowwise: 
   colA  colB  colC  all_cols_identical
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl>             
 1 w     w     w     TRUE              
 2 k     k     k     TRUE              
 3 m     m     m     TRUE              
 4 b     b     b     TRUE              
 5 y     y     y     TRUE              
 6 n     n     n     TRUE              
 7 e     e     e     TRUE              
 8 j     j     j     TRUE              
 9 q     q     q     TRUE              
10 a     a     a     TRUE              
# … with 15 more rows
```