# Predicate function to check that values across >3 columns are all equal

Tags: r, dplyr

You have a dataframe that you're analysing, and it *seems* like you have three or more columns that are identical. But, how can you tell? This is a problem I face frequently and I haven't found a fast tidyverse solution when checking more than two columns.

If you are comparing two columns, you can use:
`mutate(is_equal = col_1 == col_2)`.

But you cannot do:
`mutate(is_equal = col_1 == col_2 == col_3)`

Reprex:

```
structure(list(col_1 = c(109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
109, 109, 109, 109, 77, 77, 78, 77), col_2 = c(109, 109, 109, 
109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 77, 77, 77, 77), 
    col_3 = c(109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
    109, 109, 77, 77, 77, 77)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Check: [How do I test if three variables are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966515/how-do-i-test-if-three-variables-are-equal-r)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could use `if_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(is_equal = if_all(col_2:col_3, `==`, col_1))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 × 4
   col_1 col_2 col_3 is_equal
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>   
 1   109   109   109 TRUE    
 2   109   109   109 TRUE    
 3   109   109   109 TRUE    
 4   109   109   109 TRUE    
 5   109   109   109 TRUE    
 6   109   109   109 TRUE    
 7   109   109   109 TRUE    
 8   109   109   109 TRUE    
 9   109   109   109 TRUE    
10   109   109   109 TRUE    
11   109   109   109 TRUE    
12   109   109   109 TRUE    
13    77    77    77 TRUE    
14    77    77    77 TRUE    
15    78    77    77 FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use the combination of `rowwise()` and `c_across()` to check the columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  # or mutate(is_equal = length(unique(c_across(everything()))) == 1)
  mutate(is_equal = n_distinct(c_across(everything())) == 1) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 16 × 4
   col_1 col_2 col_3 is_equal
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>   
 1   109   109   109 TRUE    
 2   109   109   109 TRUE    
 3   109   109   109 TRUE    
 4   109   109   109 TRUE    
 5   109   109   109 TRUE    
 6   109   109   109 TRUE    
 7   109   109   109 TRUE    
 8   109   109   109 TRUE    
 9   109   109   109 TRUE    
10   109   109   109 TRUE    
11   109   109   109 TRUE    
12   109   109   109 TRUE    
13    77    77    77 TRUE    
14    77    77    77 TRUE    
15    78    77    77 FALSE   
16    77    77    77 TRUE
```

Comment: Nice and clean solution. However, it took 30 seconds to run on a tibble with 3 cols and 25,000 rows with the identical values. Is this because of rowwise?

Comment: I believe so, @akrun's method should be more efficient

Answer (score 3):

You can use `var` to test equality among multiple elements (if `var(x) == 0`, then all elements are equal).

Another option is to use `all`.

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(equal = var(c_across(col_1:col_3)) == 0,
         equal2 = all(c_across(col_1:col_3) == col_1))
```

```r
# A tibble: 16 × 5
# Rowwise: 
   col_1 col_2 col_3 equal equal2
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> 
 1   109   109   109 TRUE  TRUE  
 2   109   109   109 TRUE  TRUE  
 3   109   109   109 TRUE  TRUE  
 4   109   109   109 TRUE  TRUE  
 5   109   109   109 TRUE  TRUE  
 6   109   109   109 TRUE  TRUE  
 7   109   109   109 TRUE  TRUE  
 8   109   109   109 TRUE  TRUE  
 9   109   109   109 TRUE  TRUE  
10   109   109   109 TRUE  TRUE  
11   109   109   109 TRUE  TRUE  
12   109   109   109 TRUE  TRUE  
13    77    77    77 TRUE  TRUE  
14    77    77    77 TRUE  TRUE  
15    78    77    77 FALSE FALSE 
16    77    77    77 TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `all` and `diff`

```
data$all_equal <- apply(data,1,function (x) all(diff(x) == 0))
data
col_1 col_2 col_3 all_equal
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>    
 1   109   109   109 TRUE     
 2   109   109   109 TRUE     
 3   109   109   109 TRUE     
 4   109   109   109 TRUE     
 5   109   109   109 TRUE     
 6   109   109   109 TRUE     
 7   109   109   109 TRUE     
 8   109   109   109 TRUE     
 9   109   109   109 TRUE     
10   109   109   109 TRUE     
11   109   109   109 TRUE     
12   109   109   109 TRUE     
13    77    77    77 TRUE     
14    77    77    77 TRUE     
15    78    77    77 FALSE    
16    77    77    77 TRUE
```