# How to create a new data table based on pairwise combinations of a subset of column names?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to define a function that takes a data frame or table as input with a specific number of ID columns (e.g., 2 or 3 ID columns), and the remaining columns are NAME1, NAME2, ..., NAMEK (numeric columns). The output should be a data table that consists of the same ID columns as before plus one additional ID column that groups each unique pairwise combination of the column names (NAME1, NAME2, ...). In addition, we must gather the actual values of the numeric columns into two new columns based on the ID column; an example with two ID columns and three numeric columns:

```
ID1 <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
ID2 <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
NAME1 <- c(10,11,9,22,25,22)
NAME2 <- c(7,9,8,20,22,21)
NAME3 <- c(10,12,11,15,19,30)
DT <- data.table(ID1,ID2,NAME1,NAME2,NAME3)
```

I want the output of the function with DT as input to be

```
ID.new <- c("NAME1 - NAME2","NAME1 - NAME2","NAME1 - NAME2", "NAME1 - NAME2",
 "NAME1 - NAME2","NAME1 - NAME2", "NAME1 - NAME3", "NAME1 - NAME3",
 "NAME1 - NAME3","NAME1 - NAME3","NAME1 - NAME3","NAME1 - NAME3",
 "NAME2 - NAME3","NAME2 - NAME3","NAME2 - NAME3","NAME2 - NAME3",
 "NAME2 - NAME3", "NAME2 - NAME3")
ID1 <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","A","B","B","B")
ID2 <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
value.left <- c(10,11,9,22,25,22,10,11,9,22,25,22,7,9,8,20,22,21)
value.right <- c(7,9,8,20,22,21,10,12,11,15,19,30,10,12,11,15,19,30)
DT.output <- data.table(ID.new,ID1,ID2,value.left,value.right)
```

I have found that fun() (see below) does the job, but is too slow for my liking:

```
  fun <- function(data, ID.cols){
   data <- data.table(data)
   # Which of the columns are ID columns
   ids <-  which(colnames(data) %in% ID.cols)
   # Obtain all pairwise combinations of numeric columns into a list
   numeric.combs <- combn(x = data.table(data)[,!ids, with = FALSE], m = 2, simplify = FALSE)
   id.cols <- data[,ids, with = FALSE]
   # bind the ID columns to each pairwise combination of numeric columns inside the list
   bind.columns.each.numeric.comb <- lapply(X = numeric.combs, FUN = function(x) cbind(id.cols,x)) 
   # Create generic names for the numeric columns so that rbindlist() may be applied. In addition we make a new column that groups based on which columns we are considering
   generalize <- suppressWarnings(lapply(X = bind.columns.each.numeric.comb, FUN = function(x) 
   setattr(x = x[,ID.NEW:=paste(colnames(x[,!ids,with=FALSE]),collapse=" - ")], name = 
   'names', value = c(ID.cols,"value.left","value.right","ID.NEW"))))
   return(rbindlist(l=generalize))
}

# Performance
print(microbenchmark(fun(DT,ID.cols=c("ID1","ID2")),times=1000))
```

Is there a faster and more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Is solution with another package possible?

Comment: @TarJae, Yes, as long as it is more efficient. I have not found a package that will solve this problem more efficiently than what is seen for fun().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use a data frame, the below will give you the currently most speed and memory efficient approach (see benchmark wiki).

I think the approach using `combn()` seems reasonable to me. And I don't really think it's iterating over the combinations 18 times, [as has been purported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70498017/7941188). Moreover, I personally find this easier to read than the data table melt version, but this is probably because I'm not used to data.table syntax.

Note: using this on a data table is apparently not efficient. If you really need a data.table, r2evans solution is better.

```r
fun2 <- function(data, ID.cols){
  ids <-  which(colnames(data) %in% ID.cols)
  ## you can loop over the combinations directly
  new_dat <- combn(data[-ids], 2, function(x) {
    new_x <- setNames(x, paste("value", c("left", "right"), sep = "."))
    ## use paste with collapse for the ID.new
    new_x$ID.new <- paste(names(x), collapse = " - ")
    new_x
  }, simplify = FALSE)

## bind it with the old ID columns, outside the loop (bit faster)
  cbind(do.call(rbind, new_dat), data[ids])
}

fun2(DT,ID.cols = c("ID1", "ID2"))
#>    value.left value.right        ID.new ID1 ID2
#> 1          10           7 NAME1 - NAME2   A   1
#> 2          11           9 NAME1 - NAME2   A   2
#> 3           9           8 NAME1 - NAME2   A   3
#> 4          22          20 NAME1 - NAME2   B   1
#> 5          25          22 NAME1 - NAME2   B   2
#> 6          22          21 NAME1 - NAME2   B   3
#> 7          10          10 NAME1 - NAME3   A   1
#> 8          11          12 NAME1 - NAME3   A   2
#> 9           9          11 NAME1 - NAME3   A   3
#> 10         22          15 NAME1 - NAME3   B   1
#> 11         25          19 NAME1 - NAME3   B   2
#> 12         22          30 NAME1 - NAME3   B   3
#> 13          7          10 NAME2 - NAME3   A   1
#> 14          9          12 NAME2 - NAME3   A   2
#> 15          8          11 NAME2 - NAME3   A   3
#> 16         20          15 NAME2 - NAME3   B   1
#> 17         22          19 NAME2 - NAME3   B   2
#> 18         21          30 NAME2 - NAME3   B   3
```

For a benchmark, please see [the community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70501099/7941188).

Comment: this is great. This seems to be a very general approach that extends to "real data" with any number of name columns and ID columns. Nevertheless, I wonder, why is the data frame approach here faster than the data table?

Comment: @Pernkf Glad you like it. I don't know why that is faster! I'm not very knowledgable with data.table and don't really understand the underlying structure. Maybe the structure is different from the data frame list structure and it needs to be internally converted, and this might be a time limiting step?

Answer (score 7):

A melted, self-join option:

```r
library(data.table)
DTlong <- melt(DT, id.vars = c("ID1", "ID2"), variable.factor = FALSE)
out <- DTlong[DTlong, on = .(ID1, ID2), allow.cartesian = TRUE
  ][variable < i.variable,
  ][, .(ID.new = paste(variable, i.variable, sep = " - "),
        ID1, ID2, value.left = value, value.right = i.value)]
out
#            ID.new    ID1   ID2 value.left value.right
#            <char> <char> <num>      <num>       <num>
#  1: NAME1 - NAME2      A     1         10           7
#  2: NAME1 - NAME2      A     2         11           9
#  3: NAME1 - NAME2      A     3          9           8
#  4: NAME1 - NAME2      B     1         22          20
#  5: NAME1 - NAME2      B     2         25          22
#  6: NAME1 - NAME2      B     3         22          21
#  7: NAME1 - NAME3      A     1         10          10
#  8: NAME2 - NAME3      A     1          7          10
#  9: NAME1 - NAME3      A     2         11          12
# 10: NAME2 - NAME3      A     2          9          12
# 11: NAME1 - NAME3      A     3          9          11
# 12: NAME2 - NAME3      A     3          8          11
# 13: NAME1 - NAME3      B     1         22          15
# 14: NAME2 - NAME3      B     1         20          15
# 15: NAME1 - NAME3      B     2         25          19
# 16: NAME2 - NAME3      B     2         22          19
# 17: NAME1 - NAME3      B     3         22          30
# 18: NAME2 - NAME3      B     3         21          30

### validation
setorder(out, ID.new, ID1, ID2)
identical(DT.output, out)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

The methodology of `combn` is sound thinking, certainly, however its only inefficiency is that it iterates once per combination. That is, the function passed to `combn(..., FUN=)` is called in this case 18 times; if your data is much larger, it will be called many more times. In the case of a `merge`/join as here, though, everything is done in as vectorized a way as we can manage: `merge` is done efficiently, filtering is returned as a single logical vector, and the `paste(..)` is also one large vector.

The merge concept does have its own inefficiency, to be fair: it originally produces 54 rows due to the cartesian join. This will cause memory-exhaustion problems with much-larger data. If you run into this, it may help to use `fuzzyjoin` and include `variable < variable` (LHS vs RHS), which should reduce (if not completely remove) the problem.

This last recommendation can be done in `sqldf` as well:

```r
sqldf::sqldf("
  select t1.variable || ' - ' || t2.variable as [ID.new], t1.ID1, t1.ID2, 
    t1.value as [value.left], t2.value as [value.right]
  from DTlong t1
    join DTlong t2 on t1.ID1=t2.ID1 and t1.ID2=t2.ID2
      and t1.variable < t2.variable")
#           ID.new ID1 ID2 value.left value.right
# 1  NAME1 - NAME2   A   1         10           7
# 2  NAME1 - NAME3   A   1         10          10
# 3  NAME1 - NAME2   A   2         11           9
# 4  NAME1 - NAME3   A   2         11          12
# 5  NAME1 - NAME2   A   3          9           8
# 6  NAME1 - NAME3   A   3          9          11
# 7  NAME1 - NAME2   B   1         22          20
# 8  NAME1 - NAME3   B   1         22          15
# 9  NAME1 - NAME2   B   2         25          22
# 10 NAME1 - NAME3   B   2         25          19
# 11 NAME1 - NAME2   B   3         22          21
# 12 NAME1 - NAME3   B   3         22          30
# 13 NAME2 - NAME3   A   1          7          10
# 14 NAME2 - NAME3   A   2          9          12
# 15 NAME2 - NAME3   A   3          8          11
# 16 NAME2 - NAME3   B   1         20          15
# 17 NAME2 - NAME3   B   2         22          19
# 18 NAME2 - NAME3   B   3         21          30
```

---

Benchmarking:

```r
bench::mark(
  pernkf  = fun(DT, c("ID1", "ID2")),
  tjebo   = fun2(DT, c("ID1", "ID2")),
  r2evans = fun3(DT, c("ID1", "ID2")),  # native data.table
  r2evans2 = fun4(),                    # sqldf
  check = FALSE)
# # A tibble: 4 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory        time     gc        
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>        <list>   <list>    
# 1 pernkf       5.38ms   6.06ms     161.      287KB    13.2     61     5      379ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3~ <bch:tm~ <tibble [~
# 2 tjebo        5.08ms   5.63ms     172.      230KB     8.83    78     4      453ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3~ <bch:tm~ <tibble [~
# 3 r2evans      2.97ms   3.48ms     280.      170KB    11.0    127     5      454ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3~ <bch:tm~ <tibble [~
# 4 r2evans2    17.19ms  18.91ms      52.0     145KB    13.0     20     5      384ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3~ <bch:tm~ <tibble [~
```

(`sqldf` does take a performance hit in this example, I'd welcome improved queries :-)

Comment: why would the function be called 18 times in combn? there are only three combinations?

Comment: If speed is the only thing of importance... If you use my function on a data frame (not: data table), it's faster than yours. See benchmark results as a community wiki.

Comment: I agree to the premise that speed is not always the most important; in that tone, I think that readability and simplicity should be influential as well. I'm curious to know how well all of our solutions apply to the "real data" (if imperfectly represented by the data in the question). Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans, this is a great solution, but as far as my knowledge goes, none of these solutions are fit for arbitrarily named ID columns (I should have clarified this stronger). The idea is that one should accept any names for the ID columns, but here, ID1 and ID2 are used by name (?) for example, . on = .(ID1, ID2) :)

Comment: @Pernkf [fun2 already allows for exactly that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70496518/7941188)

Answer (score 3):

Benchmarking, reprex. If you don't really need a data table, base R seems to do the trick here.

**Note** this is comparing r2evans' and pernkf's functions on a data table with tjebo's and tarjae's function on a data frame.

The methods suggested by PeaceWang is currently not included as they are either not scalable to k columns or provide an incorrect result.

```r
bench::mark(
  pernkf  = fun(DT, c("ID1", "ID2")),
  tjebo   = fun2(DF, c("ID1", "ID2")),
  r2evans = fun3(DT, c("ID1", "ID2")), 
  tarjae = fun4(DF, c("ID1", "ID2")),
  check = FALSE)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 pernkf       2.95ms    3.2ms     302.     2.29MB     6.33
#> 2 tjebo      359.33µs 373.85µs    2423.    18.65KB    10.5 
#> 3 r2evans      1.65ms   1.79ms     535.   756.16KB     6.30
#> 4 tarjae      26.49ms  27.74ms      34.3    4.75MB     7.35

m <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  pernkf = fun(DT, ID.cols = c("ID1", "ID2")),
  r2evans = fun3(DT, ID.cols = c("ID1", "ID2")),
  tjebo = fun2(DF, ID.cols = c("ID1", "ID2")), 
  tarjae = fun4(DF, c("ID1", "ID2")),
  times = 1000
)
m
#> Unit: microseconds
#>     expr       min         lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
#>   pernkf  2885.714  3055.1450  3439.1257  3150.457  3298.404  95391.80  1000
#>  r2evans  1629.028  1739.5715  1949.8389  1829.696  1922.227  10843.33  1000
#>    tjebo   354.714   410.0975   469.1457   427.948   443.237   4344.00  1000
#>   tarjae 25854.416 26564.8420 29103.6948 27142.758 30982.328 118592.10  1000

ggplot2::autoplot(m)
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
```

[image]

Data and functions

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

ID1 <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
ID2 <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
NAME1 <- c(10,11,9,22,25,22)
NAME2 <- c(7,9,8,20,22,21)
NAME3 <- c(10,12,11,15,19,30)
DF <- data.frame(ID1,ID2,NAME1,NAME2,NAME3)
DT <- data.table(DF)

fun <- function(data, ID.cols){
  data <- data.table(data)
  ids <-  which(colnames(data) %in% ID.cols)
  numeric.combs <- combn(x = data.table(data)[,!ids, with = FALSE], m = 2, simplify = FALSE)
  id.cols <- data[,ids, with = FALSE]
  bind.columns.each.numeric.comb <- lapply(X = numeric.combs, FUN = function(x) cbind(id.cols,x)) 
  generalize <- suppressWarnings(lapply(X = bind.columns.each.numeric.comb, FUN = function(x) 
    setattr(x = x[,ID.NEW:=paste(colnames(x[,!ids,with=FALSE]),collapse=" - ")], name = 
              'names', value = c(ID.cols,"value.left","value.right","ID.NEW"))))
  return(rbindlist(l=generalize))
}

fun2 <- function(data, ID.cols){
  ids <-  which(colnames(data) %in% ID.cols)
  new_dat <- combn(data[-ids], 2, function(x) {
    new_x <- setNames(x, paste("value", c("left", "right"), sep = "."))
    new_x$ID.new <- paste(names(x), collapse = " - ")
    new_x
  }, simplify = FALSE)
  cbind(do.call(rbind, new_dat), data[ids])
}

fun3 <- function(data, ID.cols) {
  DTlong <- melt(data, id.vars = ID.cols, variable.factor = FALSE)
  out <- DTlong[DTlong, on = .(ID1, ID2), allow.cartesian = TRUE
  ][variable < i.variable,
  ][, .(ID.new = paste(variable, i.variable, sep = " - "),
        ID1, ID2, value.left = value, value.right = i.value)]
  out
}
fun4 <- function(x, id.cols){
DT1 <- DT %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -id.cols
  ) %>% 
  mutate(name1 = lead(name, default=last(name)),
         value1 = lead(value, default=last(value)))%>% 
  arrange(name, name1) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(name_nr = parse_number(name)) %>% 
  ungroup()


DT1 %>% 
  mutate(name1 = lead(name, unique(n)*(max(name_nr)-min(name_nr)))) %>% 
  mutate(value1 = lead(value, unique(n)*(max(name_nr)-min(name_nr)))) %>% 
  slice(seq_len(first(n))) %>% 
  bind_rows(DT1 %>% 
              slice(1:(n() - unique(n))), .
  ) %>% 
  mutate(ID.new = paste(name, name1, sep = " - "), .before=1) %>% 
  select(ID.new, ID1, ID2, value.left=value, value.right = value1) %>% 
  arrange(ID.new)
}
```

Check if the solutions are the same:

```
## convert all to data frame
## column names and order need to be the same
## rows need to be sorted in the same way (caveat row names!)
preparetocompare <- function(x){
x <- data.frame(x)
names(x) <- tolower(names(x))
x <- x[c("id1", "id2", "value.left", "value.right", "id.new")]
x <- x[with(x, order(id.new, id1, id2)),]
rownames(x) <- NULL
}
compare_df <- function(...){
 # credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17244041/7941188
 ls_df <-  c(as.list(environment()), list(...))
 ls_compare <- lapply(ls_df, preparetocompare)
 # inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/18814864/7941188
 all.identical <- function(l) mapply(all.equal, head(l, 1), tail(l, -1))
 all.identical(ls_compare)
}

compare_df(fun(DT, c("ID1", "ID2")), 
           fun2(DF, c("ID1", "ID2")), 
           fun3(DT, c("ID1", "ID2")),
           fun4(DF, c("ID1", "ID2"))
           )
#> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

This post consists of 3 parts:

1. The original answer (non-equi self-join with two ID columns)
2. The 1st edit (non-equi self-join with a variable number of ID columns)
3. The 2nd edit (benchmark of 6 different approaches with varying problem sizes)

#### Original answer: Non-equi self-join with two ID columns

For the sake of completeness, here is a solution which uses a *non-equi self-join* of the molten data (reshaped to long format):

```
library(data.table)
mdt <- melt(DT, id.vars = c("ID1", "ID2"))
res <- mdt[mdt, on = .(ID1, ID2, variable < variable), nomatch = NULL,
    .(ID.new = paste(x.variable, i.variable, sep = " - "), 
      ID1, ID2, value.left = x.value, value.right = i.value)]

all.equal(res, DT.output, ignore.row.order = TRUE)
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```

This approach is similar to [r2evans' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70498017/3817004) but avoids the cartesian join. I have refrained from showing benchmark results as benchmarkmarking a sample data set of 6 rows, 5 columns has only limited relevance.

#### Edit 1: Non-equi self-join with a *variable* number of ID columns

The OP has requested that the number of ID columns may vary (as a matter of fact, the names of the ID columns are passed as parameter to OP's own function).

The non-equi self-join can be enhanced to handle an arbitrary number of  ID columns:

```
library(data.table)
id_cols <- c("ID1", "ID2")
mdt <- melt(DT, id.vars = id_cols)
res <- mdt[mdt, on = c(id_cols, "variable < variable"), nomatch = NULL,
           c(.(ID.new = paste(x.variable, i.variable, sep = " - "), 
               value.left = x.value, value.right = i.value), .SD), 
           .SDcols = id_cols]

all.equal(res, DT.output, ignore.col.order = TRUE, ignore.row.order = TRUE)
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```

Note, that it is safe to use `.SD` here as `.SDcols` picks only those columns which are already used to join on (specified by `id_cols`).

#### Edit 2: Benchmark with *varying* problem sizes

The benchmarks presented so far by [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70498017/3817004) and [tjebo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70501099/3817004) only use the original dataset with 2 id columns, 3 numeric columns, and 6 rows. Due to small problem size these benchmarks compare overhead but are not representative for the performance on larger problem sizes.

There are 3 different parameters which describe the problem size:

1. The number of rows `nr` of the sample dataset `DT`,
2. the number of numeric columns `nc` from which pair-wise rows are created, and
3. the number of id columns `ni`.

The final result consists of `nc * (nc - 1) / 2 * nr` rows and `ni + 3` columns.

By using the `press()` function from the `bench` package we can easily perform a set of benchmark runs with varying problem sizes.

6 different approaches are being included in the benchmark runs:

- `pernkf()`: the function [as shown in OP's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70495334/3817004) using `combn()`,
- `r2evans()`: [r2evans' *melted self-join*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70498017/3817004) but modified to work with an arbitrary number of id columns,
- `tjebo()`: [tjebo's *base R* approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70501099/3817004) using `combn()` with a *data.frame*,
- `nej()`: a *non-equi self-join of molten data*, similar to [r2evans' approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70498017/3817004) but avoiding the cartesian join,
- `dtc()`: a data.table version of tjebos's `combn()` approach,
- `mvl()`: an implementation of [هنروقتان's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70587845/3817004) to call `melt()` with a made-up `measure.vars` list.

All approaches are implemented as functions which are called with 2 parameters, the dataset `DT`, or `DF`, resp., and a character vector with the names of arbitrary id columns.

```
pernkf <- function(data, ID.cols){
  data <- data.table(data)
  # Which of the columns are ID columns
  ids <-  which(colnames(data) %in% ID.cols)
  # Obtain all pairwise combinations of numeric columns into a list
  numeric.combs <- combn(x = data.table(data)[,!ids, with = FALSE], m = 2, simplify = FALSE)
  id.cols <- data[,ids, with = FALSE]
  # bind the ID columns to each pairwise combination of numeric columns inside the list
  bind.columns.each.numeric.comb <- lapply(X = numeric.combs, FUN = function(x) cbind(id.cols,x)) 
  # Create generic names for the numeric columns so that rbindlist() may be applied. In addition we make a new column that groups based on which columns we are considering
  generalize <- suppressWarnings(lapply(X = bind.columns.each.numeric.comb, FUN = function(x) 
    setattr(x = x[,ID.new:=paste(colnames(x[,!ids,with=FALSE]),collapse=" - ")], name = 
              'names', value = c(ID.cols,"value.left","value.right","ID.new"))))
  return(rbindlist(l=generalize))
}

r2evans = \(DT, id_cols) {
  DTlong <- melt(DT, id.vars = id_cols, variable.factor = FALSE)
  DTlong[DTlong, on = c(id_cols), allow.cartesian = TRUE
  ][variable < i.variable,
  ][, .(ID.new = paste(variable, i.variable, sep = " - "), setnames(.SD, id_cols), 
        value.left = value, value.right = i.value), .SDcols = id_cols
  ]
}

tjebo <- \(data, ID.cols) {
  ids <-  which(colnames(data) %in% ID.cols)
  ## you can loop over the combinations directly
  new_dat <- combn(data[-ids], 2, function(x) {
    new_x <- setNames(x, paste("value", c("left", "right"), sep = "."))
    ## use paste with collapse for the ID.new
    new_x$ID.new <- paste(names(x), collapse = " - ")
    new_x
  }, simplify = FALSE)
  ## bind it with the old ID columns, outside the loop (bit faster)
  cbind(do.call(rbind, new_dat), data[ids])
}

nej <- \(DT, id_cols) {
  mdt <- melt(DT, id.vars = id_cols)
  mdt[mdt, on = c(id_cols, "variable < variable"), nomatch = NULL,
      .(setnames(.SD, id_cols), ID.new = paste(x.variable, i.variable, sep = " - "), 
        value.left = x.value, value.right = i.value), 
      .SDcols = id_cols]
}

dtc <- \(DT, id_cols) {
  combn(setdiff(colnames(DT), id_cols), 2, 
        \(x) DT[, ..x][, ID.new := paste(x, collapse = " - ")], 
        simplify = FALSE) |>
    rbindlist(use.names = FALSE) |>
    setnames(1:2, c("value.left", "value.right")) |>
    cbind(DT[, ..id_cols])
}

mvl <- \(DT, id_cols) {
  num_cols <- setdiff(colnames(DT), id_cols)
  combos <- combn(num_cols, 2L, simplify = TRUE)
  id_new_levels <- apply(combos, 2, paste, collapse = " - ") 
  melt(DT, measure.vars = list(combos[1L, ],combos[2L, ]), 
       value.name = c("value.left", "value.right"), variable.name = "ID.new")[
         , ID.new := as.character(`levels<-`(ID.new, id_new_levels))]
}
```

The two approaches by [Peace Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70496109/3817004) and [TarJae](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70505959/3817004) have been omitted as I was not able to turn these into scalable functions.

In the call to `press()` the number of rows `nr` is varied from 10 to 100'000 and the number of numeric columns `nc` from 3 to 10. Correspondingly, the number of rows of the resulting datasets vary from 30 to 4.5 million rows. All runs use 3 id columns in order to verify that `ni` is scalable (and not limited to 2).

The check funtion is set to ignore different order of rows and/or columns as these may vary between the different approaches.

```
library(bench)
bm <- press(
  nr = c(10L, 1000L, 100000L),
  nc = c(3L, 5L, 10L),
  {
    ni <- 3L
    DT <- data.table()
    id_cols <- sprintf("ID%01i", seq(ni))
    # append id cols
    for (id in id_cols) set(DT, , id, seq(nr))
    # append data cols
    for (j in seq(nc)) {
      col_name <- sprintf("NAME%04i", j)
      set(DT, , col_name, seq(nr) + (j / 1000))
    }
    DF <- as.data.frame(DT)
    mark(
      pernkf(DT, id_cols),
      r2evans(DT, id_cols),
      tjebo(DF, id_cols),
      nej(DT, id_cols),
      dtc(DT, id_cols),
      mvl(DT, id_cols),
      check = \(x,y) all.equal(x, setDT(y), ignore.row.order = TRUE, ignore.col.order = TRUE),
      min_iterations = 3L
    )
  }
)
```

The benchmark timings are visualised by

```
ggplot2::autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

(note the logarithmic time scale).

Almost always, `mvl()` is the fastest approach. Only for the smallest problem sizes with 3 numeric columns and up to 1000 rows, `tjebo()` is slightly faster. For large problems with 100'000 of rows, `dtc()` and `pernkf()` are second and third, resp.

The next chart shows how performance varies with the number of numeric columns `nc`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(bm) +
  aes(nc, median, colour = attr(expression, "description")) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_log10() +
  labs(colour = "expression") +
  facet_wrap(~nr, scales = "free_y") +
  ggtitle("Median run time")
```

[image]

(note the log-log scales and the independent time scales of the facets)

`tjebo()`'s run times increase steeper with `nc` than any other approach. For some use cases, `mvl()` is about a magnitude faster than any other approach.

An often neglected aspect is memory consumption. The next chart shows how memory allocation varies with problem size:

```
ggplot(bm) +
  aes(nc, mem_alloc, colour = attr(expression, "description")) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_log10() +
  labs(colour = "expression") +
  facet_wrap(~nr, scales = "free_y") +
  ggtitle("Memory allocation")
```

[image]

(note the log-log scales and the independent scales on the y-axes)

There is a remarkably large discrepancy in memory allocation between the  best and worst approaches for each use case which is about a factor of 7 to 8. Again, `tjebo()` shows the steepest increase in memory alloction with `nc`. For large problem sizes, `mvl()` allocates less memory than any other approach followed by `dtc()` and `pernkf()`.

Answer (score 2):

**Attention**:

> Here is an inspiring idea which is not fully satisfy OP's requirement (e.g.,  ID.new and number order) but I think it worth to be recoreded here.

You can turn `DT` into long format by `melt` firstly.
Then to `shift` value with the step `-nrow(DT)` in order to do
the minus operation, i.e. `NAME1 - NAME2, NAME2 - NAME3, NAME3 - NAME1`.

```
ds = melt(DT,
          measure.vars = patterns("^NAME"),
          variable.name = c("ID.new"),
          value.name = c("value.left"))
group_len = nrow(DT)
ds[, ID.new := paste(ID.new,shift(ID.new, n = -group_len, type = c("cyclic")),sep = " - ")]
ds[, value.right := shift(value.left, n = -group_len, type = c("cyclic"))]
```

Output:

```
      ID1   ID2        ID.new value.left value.right
    <char> <num>        <char>      <num>       <num>
 1:      A     1 NAME1 - NAME2         10           7
 2:      A     2 NAME1 - NAME2         11           9
 3:      A     3 NAME1 - NAME2          9           8
 4:      B     1 NAME1 - NAME2         22          20
 5:      B     2 NAME1 - NAME2         25          22
 6:      B     3 NAME1 - NAME2         22          21
 7:      A     1 NAME2 - NAME3          7          10
 8:      A     2 NAME2 - NAME3          9          12
 9:      A     3 NAME2 - NAME3          8          11
10:      B     1 NAME2 - NAME3         20          15
11:      B     2 NAME2 - NAME3         22          19
12:      B     3 NAME2 - NAME3         21          30
13:      A     1 NAME3 - NAME1         10          10
14:      A     2 NAME3 - NAME1         12          11
15:      A     3 NAME3 - NAME1         11           9
16:      B     1 NAME3 - NAME1         15          22
17:      B     2 NAME3 - NAME1         19          25
18:      B     3 NAME3 - NAME1         30          22
```

Comment: I think the OP wants an approach that is scalable to k columns

Comment: @tjebo Of course, this is scalable

Comment: I am afraid I don't see how this is scalable in its current form.

Comment: (also, if you should care updating your answer, consider not generating a difference column, but the output given by the OP, as characters ;)

Comment: @tjebo Sure, I know what you mean (the column ID.new).  That’s just not the main difficulty, and I am a little lazy to edit without the response of OP when I am walking in a cold night.

Comment: @PeaceWang, I should clarify that the new ID column should not be a result of applying the minus-operator to the two value columns. The ID column should be linked to one of all unique combinations of column names. :) So the ID columns should show which two columns are being considered in the value columns.

Comment: I know,  you can use r2evans's solution. I just provide a new idea to solve it. The ID.new column need some small trick to fix it. But that's not what I want to show, you know that is a dirty work. This `shift` idea is more suitable for the `NAME1 - NAME2, NAME2 - NAME3, NAME3 - NAME1` case.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE II** (Removed wrong solution)

Now after really hard work and good support of the community (thanks to **@akrun** and **@tjebo**) I think I have the correct and scalable `tidyverse` solution: (HURRAY):-)

```
library(tidyverse)

DT1 <- DT %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -c(ID1, ID2)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(name1 = lead(name, default=last(name)),
         value1 = lead(value, default=last(value)))%>% 
  arrange(name, name1) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(name_nr = parse_number(name)) %>% 
  ungroup()

DT1 %>% 
  mutate(name1 = lead(name, unique(n)*(max(name_nr)-min(name_nr)))) %>% 
  mutate(value1 = lead(value, unique(n)*(max(name_nr)-min(name_nr)))) %>% 
  slice(seq_len(first(n))) %>% 
  bind_rows(DT1 %>% 
              slice(1:(n() - unique(n))), .
            ) %>% 
  mutate(ID.new = paste(name, name1, sep = " - "), .before=1) %>% 
  select(ID.new, ID1, ID2, value.left=value, value.right = value1) %>% 
  arrange(ID.new)
```

```
ID.new        ID1     ID2 value.left value.right
   <chr>         <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 NAME1 - NAME2 A         1         10           7
 2 NAME1 - NAME2 A         2         11           9
 3 NAME1 - NAME2 A         3          9           8
 4 NAME1 - NAME2 B         1         22          20
 5 NAME1 - NAME2 B         2         25          22
 6 NAME1 - NAME2 B         3         22          21
 7 NAME1 - NAME3 A         1         10          10
 8 NAME1 - NAME3 A         2         11          12
 9 NAME1 - NAME3 A         3          9          11
10 NAME1 - NAME3 B         1         22          15
11 NAME1 - NAME3 B         2         25          19
12 NAME1 - NAME3 B         3         22          30
13 NAME2 - NAME3 A         1          7          10
14 NAME2 - NAME3 A         2          9          12
15 NAME2 - NAME3 A         3          8          11
16 NAME2 - NAME3 B         1         20          15
17 NAME2 - NAME3 B         2         22          19
18 NAME2 - NAME3 B         3         21          30
```

Comment: Correct. thanks tjebo. Will fix.

Comment: @tjebo Please see my update, now with correct version!

Comment: This is under construction since the whole day and not finished now

Comment: I am almost there

Comment: Please see my update. Many thanks for the support.

Comment: well done, +1 for the effort - alas, the benchmarking doesn't look so promising... see benchmark wiki

Comment: @TarJae, thanks for your input. Your solution seems to work for this specific example, but does not extend to "real data". In one of our data sets, we have five name columns, and this solution breaks down at the "parse_number()" part (not sure why) :)

Answer (score 0):

I think since data are well structured someone may use the following code (this is scalable but for simplicity I provided a simple variant)

```
melt(DT, measure.vars=list(c(3,3,4), c(4,5,5)))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the future of human life, annoyed by `Bot` :D

Comment: @هنروقتان, this is a splendid idea, indeed! However, your answer is too terse to upvote. Please, [edit] yor answer and give more details.

Comment: @هنروقتان, I have enhanced your approach to include it in my [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70525707/3817004). Your approach is almost always the fastest and less memory allocating approach for the use cases investigated.